# OpenCV::Mat how to efficiently add a column of ones?

Tags: opencv, opencv-mat

**GIVEN:**

A matrix (N, 3) build from a point cloud, i.e. a `vector<Point3d>`

```
std::vector<cv::Point3d> pcVector = ... // from somewhere
cv::Mat                  pcMat = cv::Mat(pcVector).reshape(1);
```

Thus having `pcMat` to be something like:

```
[  0.1, 1.3, 4.5 ]
[  3.1, 1.4, 7.6 ]
   ...
[  1.1, 3.4, 4.1 ]
```

**GOAL:**

An efficient method to get a column of ones added to the matrix. That is to receive a matrix like the following from the above.

```
[  0.1, 1.3, 4.5, 1.0 ]
[  3.1, 1.4, 7.6, 1.0 ]
   ...
[  1.1, 3.4, 4.1, 1.0 ]
```

**CURRENTLY:**

```
cv::Mat  result(N, 4);
cv::Mat  ones = cv::Mat_<double>::ones(N, 1);

cv::hconcat(pcMat, ones, result);
```

**QUESTION:**

This seems to be *inefficient* since a temporary matrix full of ones needs to be created. Are there any tricks to get this done faster?

Comment: _"seems to be inefficient"_ did you profiled it?

Comment: You can try to skip allocating the `ones` matrix, and "manually" create the `result` Mat (with the proper size) by copying `pcMat` and adding the column with 1s.  However - before doing that you must profile the current code: (1) maybe it is good enough (2) you'll know if the "manual" approach actually works better.

Comment: @Miki it is obvious, that allocating, constructing, merging, and deleting a huge matrix (this is a larger point cloud) causes a significant amount of time. I would assume that a handy matrix function that does that could do much better. But no, I do not have measurements-just reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cv::convertPointsToHomogeneous`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga13159f129eec8a7d9bd8501f012d5543)

> The function converts points from Euclidean to homogeneous space by appending 1's to the tuple of point coordinates. That is, each point (x1, x2, ..., xn) is converted to (x1, x2, ..., xn, 1).

```cpp
// given
std::vector<cv::Point3d> pcVector = ... // from somewhere
cv::Mat                  pcMat = cv::Mat(pcVector).reshape(1);

// I did not run this
cv::Mat dst;
cv::convertPointsToHomogeneous(pcMat, dst); // pcVector oughta work too
```

As always, these things will accept both Nx1 K-channel Mats as well as NxK 1-channel Mats. The result seems to always be Nx1 (K+1)-channel though.

And... you can imagine what `convertPointsFromHomogeneous` would do.

Comment: This function actually perfectly seems to do what I wanted. However, it produces a `cv::Mat` of type `CV_F64C4` instead of `CV_F64C1` from `vector<Point3d>`. Thus, the result cannot be used in any matrix multiplication and `convertTo()` does not support removing channels.

Comment: if you use `cv::transform`, you can keep that shape. `transform` does matrix-vector multiplication, also for lists of vectors (Nx1 K-channel matrices, also NxK 1-ch). if you really need to, you can `Mat::reshape(1)` to convert from Nx1 K-channel (CV_64FC4) to NxK 1-channel (CV_64FC1) https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4eb96e3251417fa88b78e2abd6cfd7d8