# OpenCV Mat::convertTo(type) does not convert the type

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-mat

**GIVEN:**

The following code fragment:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    cv::Mat a = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,1) << 1,   2,   3); 
    cv::Mat b;

    std::cout << "a(before): " << cv::typeToString(a.type()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b(before): " << cv::typeToString(b.type()) << std::endl;

    std::cout <<                                             std::endl;
    std::cout << "Convert 'a' --> 'b' with type CV_64FC4" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<                                             std::endl;
    a.convertTo(b, CV_64FC4);

    std::cout << "a(after):  " << cv::typeToString(a.type()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b(after):  " << cv::typeToString(b.type()) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**EXPECTATION:**

Should produce, in my understanding, the following output:

```
a(before): CV_64FC1
b(before): CV_8UC1

Convert 'a' --> 'b' with type CV_64FC4

a(after):  CV_64FC1
b(after):  CV_64FC4
```

**OUTPUT:**

Instead, the output is as follows:

```
a(before): CV_64FC1
b(before): CV_8UC1

Convert 'a' --> 'b' with type CV_64FC4

a(after):  CV_64FC1
b(after):  CV_64FC1
```

**QUESTION:**

What is going on here? How can I actually convert to the specified target type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**:
`cv::Mat::convertTo` does not support changing the number of channels.

**Longer answer:**
As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) regarding the `rtype` paremeter of `cv::Mat::convertTo` (the one you pass `CV_64FC4` to):

> desired output matrix type or, rather, the depth since the number of
> channels are the same as the input has; if rtype is negative, the
> output matrix will have the same type as the input.

I.e. `convertTo` does not handle the case of changing the number of channels (only the bit depth of each channel).
Although it is not documented explicitly, I guess `cv::Mat::convertTo` extracts the bit depth from `rtype` and ignores the number of channels.

**In your example:** `a` has a single channels, and therefore so is `b` after the conversion.
In order to see the effect of `convertTo`, you can pass e.g. `CV_32FC1` in order to convert 64 bit `double`s to 32 bit `float`s.

---

**Update:**
According to the OP's request (in the comments below), here are examples of changing the number of channels using [`cv::mixChannels`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be):

```
cv::Mat img1c = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 1) << 1, 2, 3);
cv::Mat img4c(img1c.size(), CV_64FC4);
cv::Mat img1c_2(img1c.size(), CV_64FC1);

// Convert 1 channel into 4 (duplicate the channel):
std::vector<int> fromTo1{ 0,0, 0,1, 0,2, 0,3 }; // 0->0, 0->1, 0->2, 0->3
cv::mixChannels(img1c, img4c, fromTo1);

// Convert back to 1 channel (pick one of the channels - the 1st one in this case):
std::vector<int> fromTo2{ 0,0 };    // 0->0  (pick the 1st channel)
cv::mixChannels(img4c, img1c_2, fromTo2);
```

Comment: Hm, then why does `convertPointsToHomogeneous(vectorPoint3d, x)` produce a matrix `m` with four channels?  Seriously, I am having trouble multiplying `x` here with other matrices of type `CV_64FC1`.

Comment: I haven't used `convertPointsToHomogeneous`, but it is a different method. Why do you think it says something about the behavior of `convertTo` ?

Comment: The thing is, that a matrix (N, 4) has already four homogenous coordinates per row indicating a point. Having four channels does not make sense. Why would that thing create three more channels? How could I possibly rid them?

Comment: Not sure I understood. You can use `cv::mixChannels` to convert a 1 channel into 4 (or the other way around). If you are not familiar with it I can give an example.

Comment: yes, please give me an example.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer - see examples in my updated answer.

Comment: mixChannels is unnecessary or might not even do what he needs. there is `reshape()` and there is `convertPointsFromHomogeneous()`, as I've explained in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727013/opencvmat-how-to-efficiently-add-a-column-of-ones)

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer you need to learn about the difference between a `cv:Mat` of shape Nx1 with ***K-channel*** elements, and a `cv::Mat` of shape ***NxK*** with 1-channel elements. do you see that they are nearly equivalent? OpenCV treats those as equivalent in most situations, and prefers the former.

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727013/opencvmat-how-to-efficiently-add-a-column-of-ones), if you want to rearrange a ***Nx1 4-channel*** Mat to  ***Nx4 1-channel***, then you need to use **`cv::Mat::reshape()`**

`some_mat.reshape(1)` converts from Nx1 K-channel (CV_64FC4) to NxK 1-channel (CV_64FC1)

Docs: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4eb96e3251417fa88b78e2abd6cfd7d8

You really **don't need any of that** though, because you say you want matrix multiplication... or rather matrix-vector products. you can have that with **`cv::transform`**. transform does matrix-vector multiplication, also for lists of vectors (Nx1 K-channel matrices, also NxK 1-ch).